# ProgrammingError :No results. Previous SQL was not a query

Tags: python, sql, django-rest-framework

As I'm getting output in SQL when I try in python its showing as `ProgrammingError :No results.  Previous SQL was not a query`. even I have tried with `fetchone()` and `fetchvalue()`

here what I tried

```
@api_view(['GET'])       
def getUtilizationSummary(request, UserId):

    if request.method == 'GET':
    
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[Usp_Leftsidepanel] @UserId=%s', (UserId,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        
        print('getUtilizationSummary', result_set[0])
        data = []
        for row in result_set:
            data.append({
                'Utility':row[0],
                'Productivity':row[1],
                'BreakMeeting':row[2]
            })
        return Response(data)
```

[image: SQL output here]

Comment: You seem to have an extra comma in your parameters. (UserId,)

Comment: This is a sql server group. You need to post your question in a Python group.

Comment: I have tried without comma as well, it still the same @SeanLange

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by keeping the `SET NOCOUNT ON` on starting the query

```
@api_view(['GET'])       
def getUtilizationSummary(request, UserId):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        sql = """\
        SET NOCOUNT ON;     
        DECLARE @userid int;
        EXEC dbo.Usp_Leftsidepanel @userid = %s;
        """
        params = (UserId,)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        print('getUtilizationSummary--', result_set)
        data =[]
        for row in result_set:
            data.append({
                'Utility':row[0],
                'Productivity':row[1],
                'BreakMeeting':row[2]
            })
        return Response(data)
```